# facebook type friend search mysql query in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have created 2 tables in db. one is user_account and 2nd is user_connection.
Sending user_id1 and user_id2 in to user_connection table to make a friend request. I want to make a friend search page so need mysql query to get result of whole records of users who is in my friend list as well as not in friend list, like facebook friend search. Please help me to do the same.

[user_account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EM8Cb.png)
[user_connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQfjP.png)

Comment: Can you show us table structure along with data. ..?

Comment: yes sure. But how can I share with you. can you send me a text email from your email id chaturvedi5190@gmail.com. So i can share you the pdf files of table

Comment: Edit your question, take the screenshot of table. for more check http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask link

Comment: thanks for helping me. Shared 2 screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run two query for having friend list and not in friend list.

Try this:

> For friend list:

```
$this->db->select('user_account.*');
$this->db->from('user_account UA');
$this->db->join('user_connection UC', 'UA.id = UC.connection_id'); //User `<>` instead of `=` for not in friend list.
$this->db->where('UC.user_id', 1); // Current user Id.
$result = $this->db->get();
```

> Query will be

```
SELECT user_account.* from user_account UA 
 INNER JOIN user_connection UC ON UA.id = UC.connection_id //User `<>` instead of `=` for not in friend list.
 WHERE 
 UC.user_id = 1 // Current user Id.
```

Hope this will helpful for you.